# How to get All product max and min range in layered Navigation magento 2.2

Tags: magento2

I want to make Magento 2 filter option like this

[image]

but don't have any idea how to get max and min price range of all products in product listing page in Magento 2

thanks in advance

Comment: you can use this  https://github.com/Smile-SA/elasticsuite

Comment: this does not answer to my question @magefms

Answer (score 0):

Overwrite **Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation\FilterRenderer** and add following method:

```
/**
 * Get price range
 *
 * @param $filter
 * @return array
 */
public function getPriceRange($filter)
{
    $filterPrice = array('min' => 0 , 'max'=>0);
    if($filter instanceof \Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Price) {
        $priceArr = $filter->getResource()->loadPrices(10000000000);
        $filterPrice['min'] = reset($priceArr);
        $filterPrice['max'] = end($priceArr);
    }
    return $filterPrice;
}
```

Now inside filter.phtml try following way:

```
<?php if($filter instanceof Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Price ): ?>
    <?php $range =  $block->getPriceRange($filter);?>
```

Comment: I don't do like this, i only want to get all price range in layered navigation